# How does BootsFaces support textarea and radio buttons?

Tags: bootsfaces

I am working on a JSF application which has recently required the use of BootsFaces.  I'm new to BootsFaces (and Bootstrap as well).  After reviewing the BootsFaces website, it seems that some pretty common components seem to be missing: textarea and radiobuttons.  Perhaps I just missed them.

To be specific:  in Bootstrap, both checkboxes and radio buttons are rendered with an `<input>` element, using a type attribute of either "checkbox" or "radio", respectively.  BootsFaces has a checkbox component, but doesn't seem to have either a radio button component or a property to set on a checkbox to make it a radio button.

In Bootstrap, a single line text input field is an  element with a type attribute of "text".  A multi-line text input field is a different element, a `<textarea>`.  BootsFaces provides an inputText component, but not a textarea component.  The inputText component has a type property, but setting it to "textarea" or "textArea" does not make it into a textArea element.

Comment: You're right, these tags are missing in BootsFaces 0.7.0. Let's add them to a future version of BootsFaces. I've opened two tickets for you (https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/201 and https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/202)

Comment: Starting with version 0.8.0, BootsFaces has a `<b:inputTextarea >` component. You can see the developer preview at http://bootsfaces.net/Staging/forms/inputTextarea.jsf.

Comment: In the meantime, the link has changed: https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/inputTextarea.jsf

Answer (score 1):

**Update Mai 21, 2017**:
The current version BootsFaces 1.1.1 of BootsFaces supports both [`<b:inputTextarea />`](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/inputTextarea.jsf) and [`<b:radiobutton />`](https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/RadioButton.jsf).

**Old answer:**
Starting with BootsFaces 0.8.0, there's a `<b:inputTextarea />` component. Most likely, the radio buttons will have to wait till version 0.9.0. You can see a preview of `<b:inputTextarea />` at http://bootsfaces.net/Staging/forms/inputTextarea.jsf.